# Yii - How do I access a view from a module in the applications SiteController?

Tags: php, templates, yii, scope, yii-modules

Just wondering what i need to do to access a modules view in my SiteController class to render that view instead of the index view. i want to access the view which is found in `protected/modules/account/views/account/register.php`. I know i need to change this line in my `SiteController::actionIndex` class::method : `$this->render('index', array('model' => $model));`. but I'm not sure what i need to put to access the module's view. I tried `'account/views/account/register` but i get this exception: `CException SiteController cannot find the requested view "account\views\account\register"`

thanks for any help or direction you can provide

Comment: Did u check the manual's module part?

Comment: Note, that it's usually a sign of not so good design, if you have to do this kind of things. Modules should be self contained. It should never be neccessary to access a module view from outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By this you can access modules/mymodule/views/profile/changepassword  view

```
$this->renderPartial('application.modules.mymodule.views.profile.changepassword',array('model'=>$model));
```

Comment: I am getting this. Do you have any idea why ?  This is the view content for action "index". The action belongs to the controller "FitnessController" in the "fitness" module.

You may customize this page by editing